# How is this called in JavaScript / Node?

Tags: javascript, function

I'll post two quick examples and I'd like to know how are these called

```
$.post('/path/to/file', {param1: 'value1'}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
/*optional stuff to do after success */
});
```

In the post function there's a third parameter, which is a function, but data, textStatus and xhr are available to be used within the function, how that called? Even I use them all the time, I feel like I still do not understand the "usage" or the whole thing, I mean, how can the third parameter return or make those 3 parameters of the inner function available?

Comment: `$.post` does call it for you, and pass the arguments you receive. It's called a *callback*.

Comment: `function A(x, y, z, callback) { /* do some stuff */ if (typeof callback !== "undefined") callback(x, y, z); }` now you get to use the third param as a callback with 3 parameters when you call A

Answer (score 2):

`$.post` (along with `$.get`, `$.ajax` etc) is jQuery's "sugar" on top of the [XMLHTTPRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). The third argument, the function, is known as a **callback**, and is called once the request has completed with the request response as its argument(s). A simplified version would look like this:

```
function post(endpoint, params, callback) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = endpoint;
  var params = params;
  http.open("POST", url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

      // The callback is called with the text (and other parameters)
      // passed in as arguments
      // jQuery also returns textStatus, and the jQXHR object
      // https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
      callback(http.responseText));
    }
  }
  http.send(params);
}
```

And it's used in exactly the same way as `$.post`.

```
post('http://example.com/post', {}, function (text) {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string (the path), an object (the options dictionary), and a lambda function to jQuery.post. jQuery then performs the POST request on your behalf using the path and options, and when it is complete calls the function with the 3 arguments.

This is a callback.

Comment: I think the OP also wonder how the function manages to trigger the callback once it's done.

Comment: Exactly, and how does the callback make use of the parameters